# Typescript React React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, typescript1.8

I am using TypeScript(1.8.10) and learning react. I am using React-Bootstrap to build a simple navigation as an example and I am getting the following error. THe error prevents the dom from getting rendered. I am totally new to react so not sure what I am doing wrong here. Thank you so much for any help or pointers to get past this error.

```
    // A '.tsx' file enables JSX support in the TypeScript compiler, 
// for more information see the following page on the TypeScript wiki:
// https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JSX
/// <reference path="./../../../typings/index.d.ts" />

import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';
interface INavigationProps {
}

let Navbar = ReactBootstrap.Navbar;
let NavItem = ReactBootstrap.NavItem;
let MenuItem = ReactBootstrap.MenuItem;
let NavbarHeader = ReactBootstrap.NavbarHeader;
const dropdownItems = [
    { href: '#', name: 'Overview' },
    { href: '#', name: 'Setup' },
    { href: '#', name: 'Usage' },
];


export default class Navigation extends React.Component<INavigationProps, {}> {
    render() {

        return (
            <Navbar>
                <NavbarHeader href="homepage.html" name="Website Name"/>
                <NavItem>
                    <MenuItem link="about.html" title="About" />
                    <MenuItem link="contact.html" title="Contact" />
                    <MenuItem link="services.html" title="Services" />
                </NavItem>
            </Navbar>
        );
    }
}

    // A '.tsx' file enables JSX support in the TypeScript compiler, 
// for more information see the following page on the TypeScript wiki:
// https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JSX
/// <reference path="./../../typings/index.d.ts" />

import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';

import HeaderNavigation from "./NavigationComponent/navigation";
import Hello from "./HelloComponent/Hello";

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <HeaderNavigation />
        <Hello name="Athraya" />
   </div>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Isn't the component named `Navigation`, not `HeaderNavigation`?

Comment: @andrew  the headernavigation is just a label which as you can see is pointing to the Navigation module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your react version compatible with your react-bootstrap version, or bootstrap NAV facilities?
according to [this](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1520), maybe versions cause the error.

Or did you check react-router, because you are using Link property.did you check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36761021/error-rendering-react-bootstrap-components)?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Sahar. It turned out to be the Link Property which uses react-router. React Bootstrap is not dependent on react router and after reading through the link you provided and re reading react-bootstrap documentation I was able to get it working. I tried with the example code that is provided in react bootstrap and it works.

here is the working example in Typescript

```
export default class Navigation extends React.Component<INavigationProps, {}> {
render() {

    return (
        <Navbar inverse>
            <Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Brand>
                    <a href="#">React-Bootstrap</a>
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle />
            </Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Collapse>
                <Nav>
                    <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link</NavItem>
                    <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link</NavItem>
                    <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem divider />
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Separated link</MenuItem>
                    </NavDropdown>
                </Nav>
                <Nav pullRight>
                    <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link Right</NavItem>
                    <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link Right</NavItem>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>

    );
}
```